# How do I stop this loop from changing the value?

Tags: java

I'm trying to implement a heapsort on an array of objects which has already been created. It is meant to be sorted according to their eventTime attribute, yet each eventTime attribute is set to the same as the others by the time the queue is sorted. Is there any way to fix this so that it creates a 'priorityqueue' in ascending order?

Main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    CustomerQueue cQ = new CustomerQueue(0, 0, false);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        CustomerQueue cQ1 = new CustomerQueue(0, 0, false);
        cQ.enqueue(cQ1);
        System.out.println(cQ1.arrivalTime);
    }

    System.out.print("\n");

    PriorityQueue pQ = new PriorityQueue(0, 0, 0, false);

    while (!cQ.isEmpty()) {
        for (CustomerQueue c : cQ.array) {
            PriorityQueue pQ1 = new PriorityQueue(0, 0, 0, false);
            pQ1.eventTime = c.arrivalTime;
            pQ.enqueue(pQ1);
            System.out.println(pQ1.eventTime);
            cQ.dequeue();
        }
    }
    pQ.sort(pQ.array);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(pQ.array));
}
```

PriorityQueue:

```
class PriorityQueue {

PriorityQueue array[] = new PriorityQueue[10];
private int front;
private int rear;
private int count;
private int eventType;
double eventTime;
private double tallyTime;
private boolean paymentMethod;

public PriorityQueue(int evT, int eT, double tT, boolean pM) {
    this.eventType = evT;
    this.eventTime = eT;
    this.tallyTime = tT;
    this.paymentMethod = pM;
    front = 0;
    rear = -1;
    count = 0;
}

public void enqueue(PriorityQueue pQ) {
    if (isFull()) {
        System.out.println("OverFlow\nProgram Terminated");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    rear = (rear + 1);
    array[rear] = pQ;
    count++;
}

public void sort(PriorityQueue arr[]) {
    int n = arr.length;

    // Build heap (rearrange array) 
    for (int i = n / 2 - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        heapify(arr, n, i);
    }

    // One by one extract an element from heap 
    for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        // Move current root to end 
        int temp = (int) arr[0].eventTime;
        arr[0] = arr[i];
        arr[i].eventTime = temp;

        // call max heapify on the reduced heap 
        heapify(arr, i, 0);
    }
}

void heapify(PriorityQueue arr[], int n, int i) {
    int largest = i; // Initialize largest as root 
    int l = 2 * i + 1; // left = 2*i + 1 
    int r = 2 * i + 2; // right = 2*i + 2 

    // If left child is larger than root 
    if (l < n && arr[l].eventTime > arr[largest].eventTime) {
        largest = l;
    }

    // If right child is larger than largest so far 
    if (r < n && arr[r].eventTime > arr[largest].eventTime) {
        largest = r;
    }

    // If largest is not root 
    if (largest != i) {
        int swap = (int) arr[i].eventTime;
        arr[i] = arr[largest];
        arr[largest].eventTime = swap;

        // Recursively heapify the affected sub-tree 
        heapify(arr, n, largest);
    }
}

public void dequeue() {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("UnderFlow\nProgram Terminated");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    front = (front + 1) % array.length;
    count--;
}

public boolean isEmpty() {

    return (size() == 0);
}

public int size() {
    return count;
}

public boolean isFull() {
    return (size() == array.length);
}

public PriorityQueue peek() {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("UnderFlow\nProgram Terminated");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    return array[front];
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return eventType + " " + eventTime + " " + tallyTime + " " + paymentMethod;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two parts which are most likely wrong and the cause of your issue:

In the `heapify` method you have:

```
int swap = (int) arr[i].eventTime;
arr[i] = arr[largest];
arr[largest].eventTime = swap;
```

And in the `sort` method you have:

```
int temp = (int) arr[0].eventTime;
arr[0] = arr[i];
arr[i].eventTime = temp;
```

Assuming you want to switch the `CustomerQueue` objects around inside the array, they should be this instead:

```
// In the heapify:
CustomerQueue swap = arr[i];
arr[i] = arr[largest];
arr[largest] = swap;

// In the sort:
CustomerQueue temp = arr[0];
arr[0] = arr[i];
arr[i] = temp;
```

What your code currently does in pseudo-code is this:

CustomerQueue `ith` has for example `name = "I", eventTime = 1`
CustomerQueue `largest` has for example `name = "largest", eventTime = 2`

```
int temp = (int) arr[i].eventTime; // temp is now 1
arr[i] = arr[largest]; // Both arr[i] AND arr[largest] are now CustomerQueue largest (with name = "largest" and eventTime = 2)
arr[i].eventTime = temp; // Both arr[i] AND arr[largest] are now changed to eventTime temp (which is 1)
```

So now both `arr[i]` and `arr[largest]` will hold: `name = "largest" and eventTime = 1`, as well as ***referencing*** the same CustomerQueue-instance.